# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to enable use of .htaccess in Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am trying to get my `.htaccess` working on my Ubuntu-apache2-webserver.

For that I opened `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`,
I removed the comment sign (#) before AccessFileName .htaccess 
and replaced `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All` in

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I activated `mod_rewrite` via `a2enmod` rewrite and restarted the server.

But each time I am performing those changes and open an html-file placed inside of  /var/www/html, I get a 500 Internal Server Error for Virtual Host 80.

The same thing happened to me when placing

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

before `</VirtualHost>` into the `000-default.conf`-file instead of the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into server logfiles to find out where the problem is

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this? I am very new to all this.

Comment: In `Ubuntu` the logs you are looking for are `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you're using the `stock` configuration

Comment: Look into the configuration where the error log is written, open the logfile and past the messages

Comment: It says AllowOverwrite not allowed here: [Mon May 07 20:44:38.074642 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12406] [client 189.166.0.173:45358] /var/www/html/dkk/.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here

Comment: This was helpful as I could see that I should maybe place the .htaccess in the html-file directly. When I did that, it worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're slightly off in your syntax for `allowOverride`.  The `Directory` tag needs to be **inside** the `VirtualHost` tag.  Like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  Options Includes
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, make sure Apache has permissions to read and write to the directory `/var/www/html`

Comment: It is inside, I just didn't post the first part. Sorry!

Comment: is your `.htaccess` file empty?